# is there a program to simulate a graphics card

Tags: assembly, video-card

I am pretty new to assembly language and I want to interface with a graphics card to draw a pixel or something. I am wondering if there is a program I could use that I could interface with to draw a pixel in the program or the screen. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EASy68K](http://www.easy68k.com/) is a 68k system simulator with graphics and sound support.

[MARS](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/) is another one for MIPS, with graphics output support.

Answer (score 0):

Try an emulator such as [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page)